# Google Apps Script Convert Array of Users to Array of Email Addresses

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script in Google Apps Script.

I need to check if a user with an email user@domain.com is a viewer or editor of a folder. If the users is neither a viewer or editor I want to add that user as a viewer.

I'm using getViewers to get an array of viewers.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getViewers()

There is no way as far as I can tell to look up user by email address, only email address by user:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user#getEmail()

So I need to convert the array of viewers (users) to array of email addresses. Then I can use indexOf to check if user@domain.com is on that list.

How do I do that? From what I understand I need to use call or apply to apply a class to an array and get another array.

By the way I realize that this works, but I'm wondering if there is a faster or cleaner way to do it without having to loop through the array:

```
       var vieweremails = new Array();
    var viewers = folder.getViewers().concat(folder.getEditors()).concat(folder.getOwner()); 

   for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
   vieweremails[i] = viewers[i].getEmail()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the new user email with all the viewers emails, there is no other way other than looping through the array. Instead you can use [`addViewer(emailAddress)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addViewer(String)), as it has no effect if the user was already on the list of editors.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing that originally and I know the documentation says it has no effect, but that's not entirely accurate. When you use 'addViewer' a notification email is sent to the user. In my case this is out of the question entirely, because the script is supposed to check to make sure permissions are set correctly and will be set up to run every 30 minutes. I don't want an email going out to everybody every 30 minutes saying they are invited to view a folder. There is no way to disable that using addViewer class.

Comment: I could use [Advanced Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) as [discussed here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2829) but it seems like an unnecessary over-complication.